Finding closed form expression for the following sums involving Hermite polynomials.
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^kH_k(x)H_k(y)}{k!2^k}=\,\,?$$
If you apply the Christoffel-Darboux formula
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{H_k(x)H_k(y)}{k!2^k} = \frac{1}{n!2^{n+1}}\frac{H_{n+1}(x)H_n(y)-H_n(x)H_{n+1}(y)}{x-y}$$
on the second summation, you will get what I wanted to solve in the first place. Maybe I will write that here as well, so you can choose exactly what to solve:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{H_{2n+1}(x)H_{2n}(y)+H_{2n}(x)H_{2n+1}(y)}{2^{2n}(2n)!\sqrt{2n+1}} = \,\,?$$
It will be a great help if a closed form expression could be found for either of these
